# In MATLAB, how can I conveniently supply many arguments to a function?

Tags: function, matlab, input, arguments

I have a MATLAB function `myfun(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)` and a 30x6 matrix `A`. The way to call the function is by passing each column of `A` as a separate input argument:

```
myfun(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),A(:,4),A(:,5),A(:,6))
```

Just wondering whether there is a better way to do this without explicitly writing out so many times `A(:,*)`?

Comment: why are you passing like this? did you write this function or is this some kind of constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your function to accept both conventions:

```
function [] = myfun(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)
    if nargin==1
        v2 = v1(:,2);
        v3 = v1(:,3);
        v4 = v1(:,4);
        v5 = v1(:,5);
        v6 = v1(:,6);
        v1 = v1(:,1);
    end

    %# use v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6
    %# ...
end
```

Now you can call as both:

```
myfun(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),A(:,4),A(:,5),A(:,6))
myfun(A)
```

Usually you would do more validation to test for the correct number of arguments...

Answer (score 5):

You can first place each column of `A` in a cell of a cell array using the function [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html), then pass the cell array contents as a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html) using the `{:}` syntax:

```
B = num2cell(A,1);
myfun(B{:});
```